# How to get fetched data with correct index

Tags: php

I have issue and i'm not sure what is best way to handle it because i don't have so much experience with PHP.

So i have basic function that returns all items from database and it looks like this.

```
function getAll($mysqli) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT g.id, g.name, g.description FROM control_group as g");

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $description);
    $groups = array();

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $groups[$id] = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'name' => $name,
            'description' => $description
        );
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();;
    echo json_encode($groups);
}
```

And that function reproduce response like this

```
5:{id: 5, name: "Group 1", description: null}
11:{id: 11, name: "Group 2", description: null}
14:{id: 14, name: "Group 3", description: null}
17:{id: 17, name: "Group 4", description: null}
```

What i want to achieve here is response like this

```
0:{id: 5, name: "Group 1", description: null}
1:{id: 11, name: "Group 2", description: null}
2:{id: 14, name: "Group 3", description: null}
3:{id: 17, name: "Group 4", description: null}
```

So instead of item id i want to show correct index, i know somehow i need to check index not id, but i don't know how to correctly do it.

```
$groups[index] = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'name' => $name,
            'description' => $description
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove $id and it will keep adding in it with default indexes.

```
$i = 0;
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $groups[$i] = array(   // Remove $id
            'id' => $id,
            'name' => $name,
            'description' => $description
        );
 $i++;
    }
```

Comment: If i leave that blank then on my UI i can't get this function to enter in success, it just works when i put $groups['id'] or something else, is there a way to pass here index and not to leave this empty ?

Comment: Initialise $i = 0; Put $i there and increase it.

Comment: Updated my answer please cross check

Comment: Hello sir, can you take look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42469947/array-of-objects-returns-same-values i tried to create object like you told me here, but as you can see that object is more complex, so im wondering can you help me here too ? thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Remove `$id` from `$groups` key

```
$groups = array();

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $groups[] = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'name' => $name,
        'description' => $description
    );
}
```